# Photoshop rasterize layer style

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have a very simple psd file with 2 layers. The top layer has a layer style:

[image]

This is how it looks:

[image]

But when I try to rasterize the rounded rectangle layer, it turn it into this:

[image]

It's missing the green.

How can I export it with the green stuff? Thanks

Comment: I usually select the layer(s) and press both `Ctrl + G` and `Ctrl + E`. I find this to be the fastest method. ( of course on a mac `Cmd` instead of `Ctrl` )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add an empty layer below the vector layer.

Highlight the Vector layer and from the **Layer Panel Menu** choose *Merge Down**

*This will flatten all the effects into a single raster layer.*

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively to Scotts answer, you can right click the layer and select `Convert to Smart Object`.

It will merge the layer together with its styles, allowing you to apply new styles.

Or you can then rasterize the layer by right clicking again and selecting `Rasterise Layer`.

This works in CS5 so I assume they won't have changed too much of this for CS6.

Comment: Thanks this is what I was looking for